# Google C2D_MESSAGE permission error

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, android-c2dm

I am in the beginning stages of adding Google C2D capabilities to my application. I read over the documentation carefully but I still get an IllegalStateException. First here is the stack when I try to run my application:

```
03-24 21:29:36.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 21:29:36.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3380): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.maxap.lj3/com.maxap.lj3.MainActivity}:   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission com.maxap.lj3.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
03-24 21:29:36.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3380):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180) .......
```

I do define that permission in my manifest. Here is a copy of my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.maxap.lj3"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
   <uses-permission  android:name="android.permissions.INTERNET" />

 <uses-permission android:name="com.maxap.lj3.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.maxap.lj3.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> 
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.maxap.lj3.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

To

```
<permission android:name="com.maxap.lj3.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

You were trying to use the `com.maxap.lj3.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE` permission, but in your manifest you didn't declare it properly. You need to use `<permission>` not `<uses-permission>` to declare them.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling the app. And make sure you're installing a new apk.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your manifest slightly to the following:

```
<!-- Settings for GCM -->
<permission
    android:name="com.maxap.lj3.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.maxap.lj3.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```